# javascript windows "Yes/No" asking twice?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using below code for javascript window "Yes/No". It is firing twice. Is there any way I can avoid this? Or use any other code?. I need this code behind.

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { self.close() }</script>");
```

Comment: Is this client side or code behind?

Comment: I think we need more info.  Is the window opening twice?  I don't see how it could close twice.  Could you describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: What is firing twice and why does the javascript line have curly braces, but no semicolon?

Comment: after Windows poping up I need to click twice on "Yes" or "No" button. It should be one click to Yes or No, right.  But taking two clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using `Response.Write` where it would end up at the bottom of the page, like this:

```
 </html>
 <script language='javascript'> { self.close() }</script>
```

This will give all sorts of funky behavior, instead use [`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx?ppud=4), like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page),"close","window.close();",true);
```

If you were using update panels (which doesn't seem the case from `Response.Write()`) you would use the similar [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method.